# Auto complete a dropdown menu in a cq5 dialog based on input from a previous dialog field

Tags: aem

My custom CQ5 component has a dialog which consists of 2 drop down menus. I would like to automatically set a default value to second menu depending on whatever is the value selected from the previous drop down.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can register handlers for different events triggered by the widgets. You can use the "selectionchanged" event to register a function that will read the new content from the dropdown and then use the setValue() method in the second dropdown to put whatever you want there.

To obtain the second dropdown from the first you can use the nextSibling() method.
The [widget documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html) will help you a lot. look for "selection"

Comment: page not found 404